# what does ((v) == 0) ? 0 : 1 mean?

Tags: c

I came across to this code written in C

```
((v) == 0) ? 0 : 1
```

But I don't really understand. Is it true that it's to toggle the value v from 0 to 1? How does it work?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: If `v==0` it returns `0`, otherwise `1`. By itself it doesn't do anything, you need to do something with the return value.

Comment: Even if you would assign it back to v, it wouldn't toggle because you keep the value `0` when its `0`. You can use `v = ((v) == 0) ? 1 :0` to toggle `v`.

Comment: In computer programming, `?:` is a `ternary operator` that is part of the syntax for basic conditional expressions in several programming languages.

Comment: But admittedly, a toggle will be more clearly written as `v = !v;`

Answer (score 3):

The expression returns `0` of type `int` in case `v` is `0` otherwise 1.

So it's a needlessly obfuscated way of writing `((v) != 0)`, since the equality operators are guaranteed to return exactly `0` or `1`.

`(_Bool)(v)` would probably also be fine.

You might see weird code like yours in old C++ code where only the `==` operator is overloaded and not the `!=` one, which might be a valid rationale for the obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

```
int checkIfO(int v){
    return ((v) == 0) ? 0 : 1;
}
```

will return 0 if v == 0, else it will return 1